# Using Joomla 1.5 ACL for custom extension content - is this the right way?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, acl

I am developing a Joomla! 1.5 extention that has two types of registered users, each with access to their particular content.

I have done alot of reading on utilising the Joomla ACL implementation to achieve this. I understand that it is based on phpGACL.

I am seeking any guidance or advice if what I intend to do is the right approach.

Suppose my extension is called "classroom".

Suppose I have user types: "student" and "teacher"

Both are registered users.

"student" has access to "ebooks"
"teacher" has access to "classregister"

i assume  that I use Access Extension Objects that will extend the Access Control Objects.

```
$extACL = & JFactory::getACL();
//define permissions for teacher
$extACL->_mos_add_acl('com_classroom','accessdata','users','registered','usersection','classregister');
//define permissions for student
$extACL->_mos_add_acl('com_classroom','accessdata','users','registered','usersection','ebooks');
```

Then as need arises, I can check permissions for (say) the "ebooks" area using the following

```
//After checking if it is the right user
$user = & JFactory->getUser();
if(! $user->authorize('com_classroom','accessdata','usersection','ebooks'))
{
    JError::raiseError('403',JText::_('You are not logged in as a student'));
}
```

Have I understood the right use of the Joomla! ACL for my extension or is it wrong? Or will I have to define my own access controls.

Hope I made sense.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you mean Joomla 1.6/1.7? Joomle 1.5 didn't support proper ACL. Also Joomla 1.5 doesn't have much shelf-life left, I would avoid starting a new project with it.

Comment: I never said it is a new project. I would appreciate 1.5 specific assistance. I am fully aware of the existance of new versions

Comment: Either way your conceptual understanding of how the Joomla ACL in 1.5 (and also kind of 1.6/1.7) is correct, you extend the permission already set by the access extension object to define what controls each user group should have access to. Are you currently getting an error with this code?

Comment: No error at all. I wanted to make sure I implement it correctly. I guess you have also answered me, if you say my understanding has been ok. Hopefully when the client does an upgrade, there wont be as many modifications to the code. If that wont be the case, hopefully the logic will make sense. Thanks udjamaflip! Otherwise, if you have further advice, would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with udjamaflip.  Joomla 1.5 is outdated, and what you're looking for can easily be done in 1.6 and 1.7.  Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Surely you would know that websites ran Joomla1.5 before 1.6 and 1.7 In the real world, not everyone is up to date with the most current system